# jQuery does not load response

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery

I normally use ASP.NET MVC 2, but there were some problems with it, so I began to work with ASP.NET MVC 2 + jQuery and everything works. But there is one problem, jQuery doesn't load my reponse. On the ASP.NET MVC side I'm redering a partial view and I also get the respone on the client, but nothing is rendered. How can I solve this?

Here is the jquery code:

```
function addCredential(state, id) {
var daten = getJson(state, id);
$.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Account/SetCredential/",
        data: daten,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(partialView) {
            $('#Credentials').replaceWith(partialView);
            location.reload(); 
        }
    });
    return true;
};

function getJson(state,id) {
    var username = $('#username').val();
    return {"username": username, "credential_id": id , "state": state };
};
```

Comment: What's the `location.reload()` call for?  This will refresh the page :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem looks like `location.reload();`

That's reloading your page after you update it with AJAX, effectively returning it's state back to the way it was *before* you inserted the content with `.replaceWith()`

UPDATE:  looks like you're using `dataType: "json"` and inserting that into the DOM?  That's probably also a problem.  If the view is being returned as HTML, you should replace that with `dataType: "html"`

Comment: my problem is that nothing refresh the page... if i reload the page (with f5 Button) my self the everything is corret but jquery dosen't do that should i try a older version of jquery?

Comment: There could be a number of reasons your code is behaving unexpectedly.  Do you have Firebug for FireFox?  If so, get rid of the `location.reload()` and check the console for a) javascript errors or b) a problem with the response from the server.  You could also look into using jQuery's `.append()` or `.appendTo()` methods instead of `replaceWith()`, though I would try that as a last resort, since the problem is most likely elsewhere.

Comment: Using `location.reload()` will always give you the opposite of what you are trying to achieve, so definitely remove it.

Comment: @stephen yes i have firebug and there are no error i also try append() but it dosen't work.
yes location.reload() was just a try because nothing happens

Comment: Did you try changing the dataType?

Comment: Thx Stephen this was the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

@Konrad, try using the JSON2 library (http://www.json.org/js.html) to alert the "partialView" object in your success function to see what you're getting prior to reloading the page.  Also, make sure $('#Credentials') is returning an object.  When I run into issues when trying to select elements on the page, I usually check the length value of the jQuery object that is returned.  If length = 0, then you're not getting the element.

UPDATE:
Also, if you're trying to inject HTML into $('#Credentials'), then partialView may not be the correct format.  The success function accepts an object argument which comes from parsing of the responseText of the web method you called to get what you call partialView.

UPDATE: 
Check http://encosia.com/2010/03/03/asmx-and-json-common-mistakes-and-misconceptions/ for more info using $.ajax.  Lots of great info on this blog.

UPDATE: 
This is how I use JSON lib to view the data that is returned.
alert(JSON.stringify(partialView));

Comment: Thx for your help the dataType was the problem.